# data.matrix vs data.frame and data.matrix vs as.matrix

Tags: r, matrix

**How do `data.matrix` and `data.frame` differ?**

I understand that `matrix` and `data.frame` are different but I want to specifically know what are the differences between `data.frame` and `data.matrix`.

**Are `matrix` and `data.frame` the same?**

- Is `data.matrix` the same as `matrix` in `R`?
- Are conversion results of `data.matrix` and `as.matrix` the same? or how do they vary?

Comment: As you are a new member, here a general hint: if an answer actually answers your question, you should mark it as "accepted". This way the question is no longer in the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the R documentation (type `?data.matrix`), *data.matrix*  is a conversion function to transform a *data.frame* into a *matrix* which automatically transforms categorial data into numbers.

Even if the *data.frame* contains purely numeric data, the conversion can occasionally necessary to apply operations or functions that are only defined for matrices, e.g. multiplication:

```
> x <- mtcars[1:3, 1:2]
> x %*% c(1,2)
Error in x %*% c(1, 2) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
> data.matrix(x) %*% c(1,2)
              [,1]
Mazda RX4     33.0
Mazda RX4 Wag 33.0
Datsun 710    30.8
```

Compared to `as.matrix`, the defualt type conversion rules are different:

```
> x <- data.frame(a=as.factor(c("a","b")), b=c(1,2))
> as.matrix(x)
     a   b  
[1,] "a" "1"
[2,] "b" "2"
> data.matrix(x)
     a b
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 2 2
```

Note that there is yet another function: `model.matrix`, which is used to compute from a *data.frame* and a *formula* the predictor array used in a linear model. Example:

```
> m <- lm(mpg ~ poly(wt, 2), data=mtcars)
> head(model.matrix(m), n=3)
              (Intercept) poly(wt, 2)1 poly(wt, 2)2
Mazda RX4               1  -0.10963100  -0.04278415
Mazda RX4 Wag           1  -0.06282329  -0.09005145
Datsun 710              1  -0.16469889   0.03540332
```

Or directly, without the detour across `lm`:

```
> m <- model.matrix(~poly(wt, 2), data=mtcars)
> head(m, n=3)
              (Intercept) poly(wt, 2)1 poly(wt, 2)2
Mazda RX4               1  -0.10963100  -0.04278415
Mazda RX4 Wag           1  -0.06282329  -0.09005145
Datsun 710              1  -0.16469889   0.03540332
```

Comment: Since `as.data.matrix` function is not there, `as.matrix` and `data.matrix` are same as both of them convert it to matrix, what could be the difference?

Comment: The data type conversions are different between `as.matrix` `data.matrix`. Try it out!

Comment: I have added an example that shows a different behavoiour of `as.matrix` and `data.matrix`.